# What does the word "jiken" on young Luffy's shirt mean in Japanese?

Tags: one-piece, japanese-language

In *One Piece* manga, young Luffy wears a shirt containing the word "jiken".

[image]

What does "jiken" mean in Japanese?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, *jiken* ([事件](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)) means "incident" or "case".

The full picture indicates *tamago jiken* which literally means "the egg incident" where a chick is killed due to the egg getting cracked.

There might not be any deeper meaning considering Oda's nature of humor.